# Load wiki page and contents with gwtwiki

Tags: java, android, mediawiki-api, bliki

For developing android application which shows my own wiki (mediawiki) content, I wanna use [gwtwiki](https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki/overview) or bliki.

I tried a lot to read the contents or pages but nothing done.

Here is one of the test I've done:

```
public void readContent() {
    String[] listOfTitleStrings = { "Main Page", "API" };
    User user = new User("", "", "http://192.168.0.2/mediawiki/api.php");
    user.login();
    List<Page> listOfPages = user.queryCategories(listOfTitleStrings);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Pages size: " + listOfPages.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    for (Page page : listOfPages) {
        for (int j = 0; j < page.sizeOfCategoryList(); j++) {
            Category cat = page.getCategory(j);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), cat.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

For this sample the size of pages is 0. I used `user.getContent(listOfTitleStrings);` but nothing happened again.

How can I use gwtwiki?
Must I read the page by `HTML` `GET` command and fetch the XML from response content then show it? Or gwtwiki do it itself?

Comment: Does your wiki actually have a page called "Main Page"? Maybe when you've installed it, you set a language other than English, so the actual main page has different name?

Comment: @svick Of course yes, I installed mediawiki and didn't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I figure out by debugging my application, [gwtwiki](http://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/) or [bliki](http://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/) has error on read `XML` in android platform.

I made new **Android project** and changed it to **Library**. Then I copied the core part and resources folder of bliki to it without renaming. Then it's used in my application as a library. So I faced some error on running my application such as XML Parser instantiation error on constructor of AbstractXMLParser class.

I changed the code on constructor of `AbstractXMLParser` class and it is working well:

```
fXMLReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
```

instead of:

```
fXMLReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
```